# what would be the correct way to write this code?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to create a program that allows the entry of 3 astronaut names and then performs a 10 second countdown for take-off. I want it to only countdown if 3 names are entered, if less, exit or ask again. And on launch, wish ‘Bon Voyage’ to each astronaut by name.

```
#Create Blast Off program#
print("-----------------")
print("Blast Off Program")
print("-----------------")
print("")
print("Welcome to the NASA SHuttle Launch Facility 1.0")
print("To proceed you must enter 3 astrounat's names:")
print("")
names = []
counter = 0
#loop until 3 astronauts names are entered#
while counter !=3:
    counter = counter + 1
#ask the user to add astronauts name to the list#
    name1 = input("Astronaut name: ").title()
    names.append(name1)
print("")
for items in names:
    print("Astronaut's name", counter, ":", name1)#prints out the names#
print("")
print ("You have entered 3 names. The system is now live and the countdown will commence")
for i in range(10,-1, -1):#starts at 10, end at 0. reduces number by 1 each time
    print(i)
else:
    print(" exit program or ask again")
print("BLAST OFF")
print("Bon Voyage and Good Luck to our brave astronauts:")
for items in names:
    print("Astronaut's name:", name1)`
```

Comment: In the `while` loop, check if `name1` is empty. If it is, don't append it to the list and don't increment the counter.

Comment: There's no need for the `counter` variable, you can just use `while len(names) < 3:`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I want it to..." Okay, so what exactly is your question about this? Did you try to do these things? What do you think are the logical steps to solve the problem? What part can't you do?

Comment: "I want it to only countdown if 3 names are entered" I don't see the problem. You have a loop that unconditionally runs 3 times, and has the user enter a name each time. Or is there some kind of input that you don't want to accept as "a name"? If so, *what is the rule* that tells you whether the result from `input("Astronaut name: ").title()` is "a name" or not?

Comment: "And on launch, wish ‘Bon Voyage’ to each astronaut by name." Okay, so do I understand correctly that the last `for` loop at the end of your code is *trying* to do this? Does it work? If it doesn't work, what goes wrong? Now, try *looking* at the code closely. Do you see an issue? Hint: when you do `for items in names:`, what does that mean? What do you think will be the value of `items` each time through the loop? Do you see a way to use that value to solve the problem?

Comment: sorry to all of you for any inconvenience caused. I am new to python and i am afraid that i am not always as clear as i like. I will try my best to be as clear as possible in future.  Sorry once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should cover all the points you have made in a more pythonic way.

- it will stay in the while loop until three non empty strings are given for name
- it does the count down
- it will wish bon voyage to each astronaut personally

```py
# Create Blast Off program
print("""\
Blast Off Program
-----------------

Welcome to the NASA SHuttle Launch Facility 1.0
To proceed you must enter 3 astrounat's names:

-----------------
""")

names = []

while len(names) < 3:  # loop until 3 astronauts names are entered
    name = input("Astronaut name: ")  # ask the user to add astronauts 
    if name:  # empty string is falsy, if empty don't append
        names.append(name.title())

print()

for i, name in enumerate(names):
    print("Astronaut's name", i, ":", name)  # print out the names

print()

print("You have entered 3 names. The system is now live and the countdown will commence")

for i in range(10, -1, -1):  # starts at 10, end at 0. reduces number by 1 each time
    print(i)

print()
print("BLAST OFF")

for name in names:
    print("Bon Voyage and Good Luck to :", name)
```

Comment: This work fantastically! Sorry if any inconvenience was caused, I am new to python so cannot always do some of the things i would like to do myself(hence me asking this question). Is there any way for the first person's number to be no. 1, the second person no.2 etc. rather than the first name entered to be written as number 0??

Comment: Glad I could help, you really weren’t far off. As for the 0,1,2 vs 1,2,3, that’s just python 0-indexing, simplest way to overcome it would be to print `i+1` instead of just `i`.

Comment: PS: you might also want to look into [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) as a next step to have better control over those print statements.

Comment: Will do! Thanks so much!! 